# Is there a way to update a readonly array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I do have two arrays

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4] //readonly array
arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

arr1 is the main array and I want to update it with contents from arr2 so that when i log arr1 it will display

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

is there a way I can do  this

Comment: Don't declare it as read only

Comment: it comes from the API as readonly array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
let arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
arr1 = [...new Set([...arr1 ,...arr2])];

console.log(arr1); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: tried this but doesn do what i want

Comment: I have updated code to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
var mergedArray = new Array(...arr1, arr2) // [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
var finalArray = []

mergedArray.forEach(item => {
    if (!finalArray.includes(element)) { 
        finalArray.push(element);
    }
})

console.log(finalArray) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

mergedArray will be a new array that we create by merging both arr1 and arr2. Then we check for unique elements in mergedArray by using the forEach method and add non-repeating elements to finalArray.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.